# Kibana cannot load the data correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, canvas, kibana, elk

I follow the tutorial of [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.15/canvas-tutorial.html#_show_off_your_data_with_charts) to visualsize use canvas area chart.

I set the data use elasticsearch sql.

```
SELECT order_date, taxless_total_price FROM "kibana_sample_data_ecommerce" ORDER BY order_date
```

And the data preview is OK.
[image]

Then I set the option like below,

[image]

but It not show the correct data, and draw nothing.